# How do I make this character counter be insensitive to case?

Tags: python

I wrote this little code to count occurrences of words in a text:

```
string=input("Paste text here: ")
word=input("Type word to count: ")
string.count(word)
x=string.count(word)
print (x)
```

The problem is that it is case sensitive. How can I make it be case insensitive?

Comment: I would recommend not naming your variable `str`, given the fact that it's also the name of the type `str`

Answer (score 24):

Convert both the text and the word you're searching for to uppercase.

```
string.upper().count(word.upper())
```

Since strings are immutable, it won't permanently change the text or the word.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.lower()` or `.upper()` to convert your inputs to all uppercase or lowercase

```
string=input("Paste text here: ").lower()
word=input("Type word to count: ").lower()
string.count(word)
x=string.count(word)
print (x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.lower()` or `.upper()` to convert your inputs to all uppercase or lowercase.

```
string= input("Paste your text: ")
word = input("Type word to count: ")
print(f"{string.lower().count(word.lower())}")
```